# Overlaying bitmap over another bitmap

Tags: android

If I have 2 bitmaps (b1 and b2). How can  I generate a 3rd bitmap (b3) that is a result of b2 drawn over b1?  If I can modify b1 by drawing b2 over it then I think that would be better (for memory).

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a bitmap backed Canvas

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap1);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2);
```

That will overwrite bitmap 1.  If you want to avoid that, create a new bitmap first and pass that to the constructor of Canvas, then draw bitmap 1 and 2 to it.

Comment: Awesome. However will bitmap1 be modified or  I have to call something on the canvas to return to me the modified bitmap?

Comment: Bitmap1 will be modified.